# VBA Filtering Out Data from Two Columns

Tags: excel, vba, filter, multiple-columns

I have the following code which filters out data from two Columns. The first filter out values between +1 and -1.
The second filter will filter out based on a value, such as Adam.

The +1 -1 works perfectly, but the Adam filter is not filtering Adam out. Thoughts?

```
If SourceWS.AutoFilterMode Then SourceWS.AutoFilterMode = False

With SourceWS.Range("A5:BW5")

.AutoFilter _
Field:=52, _
Criteria1:="<-1", _
Operator:=xlOr, _
Criteria2:=">1"

.AutoFilter _
Field:=75, _
Criteria1:="<>Adam"



End With
```

Comment: I can't repro - this works for me.

Comment: Adam keeps coming up in my data results after filtering!! Is my method correct ?!

Comment: What column are you looking at? Just to double check, Adam is in column BW?

Comment: Yes, which corresponds to Field 75 (if my math is right)

Comment: No need of math... In such a case is good to use formula `= Columns()` in one cell of the specific column and it will return its number. In your case it is correct. But your code looks able to work as you need. I also think that it must be something with your data. Maybe your `Adam` is in fact `Adam  `... I mean, maybe it has some extra spaces.

Comment: "Adam" and "Adam " are different. Check the values in those rows you want to filter out, maybe they have extra spaces.